# sequence of mathematical actions divided by groups in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, plyr

I have data. Here example

```
 mydat=structure(list(ItemRelation = c(11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 
11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 
11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 
11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 
11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 
11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 
11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 
11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 
11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 11627L, 11627L, 
11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 
11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 
11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 
11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 
11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 
11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 
11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 
11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 11627L, 11627L
), SaleCount = c(0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 38L, -14L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 33L, 0L, -10L, -2L, 0L, 22L, -4L, 0L, 0L, -5L, 3L, 0L, 
28L, -14L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 21L, -5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
32L, -8L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 33L, -7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, -3L, 
47L, -22L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 26L, -3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 
0L, 6L, 0L, 38L, -14L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 33L, 0L, -10L, 
-2L, 0L, 22L, -4L, 0L, 0L, -5L, 3L, 0L, 28L, -14L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 21L, -5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 32L, -8L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 33L, -7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, -3L, 47L, -22L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 26L, -3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L), DocumentNum = c(3270L, 3270L, 
3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 
3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 
3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 
3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 
3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 
3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 
3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 3270L, 
3270L, 3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 
3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 
3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 
3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 
3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 
3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 
3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 
3271L, 3271L, 3271L, 3271L), IsPromo = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("ItemRelation", 
"SaleCount", "DocumentNum", "IsPromo"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-132L))
```

Data contains two group by ItemRelation+DocumentNum columns.

```
11628   3270
11627   3271
```

There is Ispromo column. It can take only two values
0 or 1.
So i need for zero category of Ispromo by SaleCount get sum of not negative or zero values. `Only` sum of positive value.
In this case

6
38
33
22
3
28
21
6

```
sum=157.
```

Then i need get sum `only` for negative value

```
-14
-10
-2
-4
-5
-14
-5


sum=-54
```

Then i must these two values to add!
`157+-54=103` After, I need 103 to divide by the total number of positive values.
Here only 8 positive value. 103/8=12,875. For zero category of ispromo column.

## For First category of Ispromo

by salescount i need get sum  of all values and positive and negative.

```
32
-8
6
33
-7
3
-3
47
-22
26
-3

sum=104
```

Then this result i need divide on total count positive value.
It is `6`

```
 32
6
33
3
47
26


104/6=17,33333333
```

And the end result. From this value `(17,33333333`) i need sustract the result for `Zero category of ispromo when we 103 divided by the total number of positive values.`

```
*103/8=12,875*
```

and multiply it by count of positive values of first category of ispromo
in our case it is `6`
17,33333333-(12,875*6)= -59,91666667

This mathematical operation must be done for each groups

```
11628   3270
11627   3271
```

How to do it?
As expected output

```
  ItemRelation DocumentNum Ispromo_by_SaleCount_sum_of_not_negative_or_zero_value for_negative_value
1        11628        3270                                                    157                -54
2        11627        3271                                                    157                -54
  substract_positive_and_negative Ispromo_by_salescount_i_need_get_sum_all_values_and_positive_and_negative
1                             103                                                                       104
2                             103                                                                       104
  divide_on_total_count_positive_value._It_is_5 end_result
1                                        12.875      -59.9
2                                        12.875      -59.9
```

or dput expected result

```
    expect=sstructure(list(ItemRelation = c(11628L, 11627L), DocumentNum = 3270:3271, 
    Ispromo_by_SaleCount_sum_of_not_negative_or_zero_value = c(157L, 
    157L), for_negative_value = c(-54L, -54L), substract_positive_and_negative = c(103L, 
    103L), Ispromo_by_salescount_i_need_get_sum_all_values_and_positive_and_negative = c(104L, 
    104L), divide_on_total_count_positive_value._It_is_5 = c(12.875, 
    12.875), end_result = c(-59.9, -59.9)), .Names = c("ItemRelation", 
"DocumentNum", "Ispromo_by_SaleCount_sum_of_not_negative_or_zero_value", 
"for_negative_value", "substract_positive_and_negative", "Ispromo_by_salescount_i_need_get_sum_all_values_and_positive_and_negative", 
"divide_on_total_count_positive_value._It_is_5", "end_result"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

## edited with data specific

How to do that if for zero category of ispromo  by SaleCount i have only zero or negative values then x4 must be =0 by default.
as well as there is another variant:
if for one category of ispromo  by SaleCount only zero or negative values
then X6 calculated as X6=0-x4.
Here the data
and of cource can be two variants at a same time, like in my example.

```
mydat=structure(list(ItemRelation = c(11709L, 11709L, 11709L, 11709L, 
11709L, 11709L, 11709L, 11709L, 11709L, 11709L, 11709L, 11709L, 
11709L, 11709L, 11709L, 11709L, 11709L, 11709L, 11709L, 11709L, 
11709L, 11709L, 11709L, 11709L, 11709L, 11709L, 11709L, 11709L, 
11709L, 11709L, 11709L, 11709L, 11709L, 11709L, 11709L, 11709L, 
11709L, 11709L, 11709L, 11709L, 11709L, 11709L, 11709L, 11709L, 
11709L, 11709L, 11709L, 11709L, 11709L, 11709L, 11709L, 11709L
), SaleCount = c(0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -2L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, -1L, -1L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, -2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, -2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), DocumentNum = c(1002L, 
1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 
1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 
1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 
1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 
1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 
1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L), IsPromo = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L)), .Names = c("ItemRelation", "SaleCount", "DocumentNum", 
"IsPromo"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -52L))
```

here output

```
ItemRelation DocumentNum CalendarYear        X1        X2        X3 X4        X5     X6
1        11709        1002         2018 any value any value any value  0 any value 0-x4=0
```

Comment: Please check again the data you provided and your calculations. Seems that you forget values. There's a `3` and a `-2` you ignore in your calculations. Then, you have to explain how you end up with `6` for "the total number of positive values" and then you say `5` ignoring the value `33`...

Comment: @AntoniosK, i wanted ask you yesterday, but something wrong was my internet. Thank you for your notice, i edited post. I really forgot any value paste. Please check it. I updated post. There many values, some I inadvertently missed.

Comment: Makes sense now :) I've posted a solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

mydat %>% 
  group_by(ItemRelation, DocumentNum) %>% 
  summarise(X1 = sum(SaleCount[SaleCount > 0 & IsPromo == 0]), 
            X2 = sum(SaleCount[SaleCount < 0 & IsPromo == 0]), 
            X3 = X1 + X2, 
            X4 = X3/sum(SaleCount > 0 & IsPromo == 0),
            X5 = sum(SaleCount[IsPromo == 1]),
            X6 = X5/sum(SaleCount > 0 & IsPromo == 1) - 
                 X3/sum(SaleCount > 0 & IsPromo == 0)*
                 sum(SaleCount > 0 & IsPromo == 1)) %>% 
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 2 x 8
#   ItemRelation DocumentNum    X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6
#          <int>       <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
# 1        11627        3271   157   -54   103  12.9   104 -59.9
# 2        11628        3270   157   -54   103  12.9   104 -59.9
```

As you can see, the key in this process is to be able to `sum` column `SaleCount` using the appropriate subset of values. For example: `sum(SaleCount[SaleCount > 0 & IsPromo == 0])` will calculate the `sum` only for positive `SaleCount` and `IsPromo` equal to `0`.

In a similar way we can use `sum(SaleCount > 0 & IsPromo == 0)` to count the observations that have positive `SaleCount` and `IsPromo` equal to `0`, because we're getting the `sum` of a (logical) vector of `TRUE` and `FALSE` values.

For your edit try this:

```
mydat %>% 
  group_by(ItemRelation, DocumentNum) %>% 
  summarise(X1 = sum(SaleCount[SaleCount > 0 & IsPromo == 0]), 
            X2 = sum(SaleCount[SaleCount < 0 & IsPromo == 0]), 
            X3 = X1 + X2, 
            X4 = ifelse(sum(SaleCount > 0 & IsPromo == 0)==0, 0, X3/sum(SaleCount > 0 & IsPromo == 0)),
            X5 = sum(SaleCount[IsPromo == 1]),
            X6 = ifelse(sum(SaleCount > 0 & IsPromo == 1)==0, -X4,  
                        X5/sum(SaleCount > 0 & IsPromo == 1) - 
                        X3/sum(SaleCount > 0 & IsPromo == 0)*
                        sum(SaleCount > 0 & IsPromo == 1))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate_all(~ifelse(. %in% c(-Inf, Inf), 0, .))
```

Comment: AntoniosK, i have any trouble when  analyzing the data. There is any situation which can be in data. I edited post. Please, can you help me in these situation? Thank you.

Comment: The problem occurs because the denominator is `0`. The easiest way to solve it is to update any columns that are `-Inf` or `Inf` by adding in the end of the process this: `... %>% mutate_all(~ifelse(. %in% c(-Inf, Inf), 0, .))`. Have a look and let me know if it works.

Comment: it is work, but the problem is that when i caluclate, i  use condition  if for zero category of ispromo by SaleCount i have only zero or negative values then x4 must be =0 by default. as well as there is another variant: if for one category of ispromo by SaleCount only zero or negative values then X6 calculated as X6=0-x4.... And not just replace inf to 0.  Because if X4=5, then 6-x4=1 or  x6 =0 and 0-x4=-5. In the result the negative value can be important.  How to incluse these additional condition in script?

Comment: I've updated my answer. I got the update for `X4`, but I'm not so sure I got the `X6`. Have a look and let me know.

Comment: AntoniosK , i tested it, all good work:)))  But last detail:: if for one category of ispromo by SaleCount only zero or negative values then X6 calculated as X6=0-x4. if x4=-5, then x6=0--5=5, it is wrong, and correct answer -5. (it is mean that effect from action=-5 , all bought stuff was return to manufacturer.) How to take into account this aspect?

Comment: Try `X6 = ifelse(sum(SaleCount > 0 & IsPromo == 1)==0, -abs(X4), ...`, which is minus the absolute value of `X4`